# Change qedsymbol and font shape within a ntheorem framed environment

Tags: framed, ntheorem

Good morning: After a lot of proofs changing variables and parameters as suggested in the documentation of ntheorem package and others, I'm not been able to replace the qedsymbol with \blacksquare and to change the shape of the theorem body font to regular shape (not italiziced). Can someone help me? Thanks!

The source follows.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{book}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{amssymb} % Conjunto de símbolos matemáticos
%\usepackage{amsthm}  % Formato para enunciados y demostraciones
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{framed}
\usepackage{pstricks}
%
\usepackage[amsthm,thmmarks,framed]{ntheorem}
\theoremseparator{:}
\newtheorem{Theorem}{Theorem}
\theoremstyle{plain}
%
\newtheorem{Proposition}{Proposition}
%
\newframedtheorem{importantTheorem}[Theorem]{Theorem}
%
\newframedtheorem{importantProp}[Proposition]{Proposition}
%
\theorembodyfont{\normalfont\bfseries}
%
\renewcommand{\qedsymbol}{$\blacksquare$}
%\theoremsymbol{\ensuremath{_\blacksquare}}
%
\begin{document}
\chapter{First chapter}
% Main text
Blabla bla The above properties carry over to all subsequent newtheorem statements
until they are set differently. Initially, they have default values.
The following two properties apply only to the very next newtheorem and
are then automatically reset:
%
\begin{Theorem}
The above properties carry over to all subsequent newtheorem statements
until they are set differently. Initially, they have default values.
The following two properties apply only to the very next newtheorem and
are then automatically reset: blablabla
\end{Theorem}
%
Bla bla bla bla
%
\begin{proof}
The above properties carry over to all subsequent newtheorem statements
until they are set differently. Initially, they have default values.
The following two properties apply only to the very next newtheorem and
are then automatically reset:
\end{proof}
%
\begin{importantTheorem}[Important Theorem]
The above properties carry over to all subsequent newtheorem statements
until they are set differently. Initially, they have default values.
The following two properties apply only to the very next newtheorem and
are then automatically reset:
\end{importantTheorem}
%
\begin{importantProp}[Important Proposition]
This is an important theorem.
The above properties carry over to all subsequent newtheorem statements
until they are set differently. Initially, they have default values.
The following two properties apply only to the very next newtheorem and
are then automatically reset:
\end{importantProp}
%
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to TeX SX! Your problem comes from using the `amsthm` option. Here is a solution (I'm not sure to have fully understood all your problems, so please let me know if it's not exactly what you want):

```
    \documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{book}
    \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
    \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
    \usepackage{lmodern}
    \usepackage[english]{babel}
    \usepackage{amssymb} % Conjunto de símbolos matemáticos
    %\usepackage{amsthm} % Formato para enunciados y demostraciones
    \usepackage{amsmath}
    \usepackage{enumitem}
    \usepackage{framed}
    \usepackage{pstricks}
    %
    \usepackage[thmmarks,framed]{ntheorem}%

    \theoremseparator{:}
    \theoremstyle{plain}
    \theoremheaderfont{\normalfont\bfseries}
    \theorembodyfont{\upshape}
    %
    \newtheorem{Theorem}{Theorem}
    \newtheorem{Proposition}{Proposition}
    %
    \newframedtheorem{importantTheorem}[Theorem]{Theorem}
    %
    \newframedtheorem{importantProp}[Proposition]{Proposition}

    %
    \theoremstyle{nonumberplain}
    \theoremheaderfont{\itshape}
    \theorembodyfont{\upshape}
    \theoremsymbol{$\blacksquare$}
    \newtheorem{proof}{Proof}
    %
    \begin{document}
    \chapter{First chapter}
    % Main text
    Blabla bla The above properties carry over to all subsequent newtheorem statements
    until they are set differently. Initially, they have default values.
    The following two properties apply only to the very next newtheorem and
    are then automatically reset:
    %
    \begin{Theorem}
    The above properties carry over to all subsequent newtheorem statements
    until they are set differently. Initially, they have default values.
    The following two properties apply only to the very next newtheorem and
    are then automatically reset: blablabla
    \end{Theorem}
    %
    Bla bla bla bla
    %
    \begin{proof}
    The above properties carry over to all subsequent newtheorem statements
    until they are set differently. Initially, they have default values.
    The following two properties apply only to the very next newtheorem and
    are then automatically reset:
    \end{proof}
    %
    \begin{importantTheorem}[Important Theorem]
    The above properties carry over to all subsequent newtheorem statements
    until they are set differently. Initially, they have default values.
    The following two properties apply only to the very next newtheorem and
    are then automatically reset:
    \end{importantTheorem}
    %
    \begin{importantProp}[Important Proposition]
    This is an important theorem.
    The above properties carry over to all subsequent newtheorem statements
    until they are set differently. Initially, they have default values.
    The following two properties apply only to the very next newtheorem and
    are then automatically reset:
    \end{importantProp}
    %
    \end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Yes! It is exactly as I want. Thanks a lot!